# Parsing XML files with special characters

Tags: objective-c, xml, ios5, xcode4.3

I try to parse a list of persons and pollute a UITableView with the names. But the persons I want to parse have special character (ä, ö, ü). Now if I start parsing the name "Gött" it is "ött" afterwards. Really strange, any ideas? Thanks a lot!

```
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    tweets          = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"lehrer"]) 
    {
        currentTweet = [Tweet alloc];
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"name"]) 
    {
        currentTweet.content = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"vorname"]) 
    {
        currentTweet.vorname = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"created_at"]) 
    {
        currentTweet.dateCreated = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"lehrer"]) 
    {
        [tweets addObject:currentTweet];
        [currentTweet release];
        currentTweet = nil;
        [currentNodeContent release];
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [parser release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behaviour - parser:foundCharacters can be called multiple times for one string (and tends to be for accented characters). Your string isn't complete until the end of the element, so store them and use the full string when you get to the end of the block. 
It is in the documentation for foundCharacters

[Apple developer docs on NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

> The parser object may send the delegate several parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an element. Because string may be only part of the total character content for the current element, you should append it to the current accumulation of characters until the element changes.

Edit as per question:

the code in general is fine but in the characters function, do

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if(nil == currentNodeContent)
        currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentNodeContent appendString:string];
}
```

then in both didStart and didEnd call a method that checks to see if the string is nil, do whatever it was you were going to do with it in the first place, and then release the string (and null it).

The string is ended at both the start of a new element (ie, the text before an opening <), and at the end (the bit of text before the

Comment: well, I can't find a way to make it working. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. Could you specify what you would do?

Comment: Edited the question to add what I would do (although NSLog is probably your first option)

Comment: I tried that too but if I do it, I get ALL the things I parse into my tableViewCell. But I just want to display the name of the person. I think that's because the string includes all of the informations, isn't it? What can I do? Thanks

Comment: I would just check on endElement and add text with  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: just to get rid of the extra.

Answer (score 3):

As per Woody's answer, this is completely expected. You will need to concatenate the strings from the multiple `- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string` calls.

The correct way to do this is as follows:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (currentElementContent== nil)
        currentElementContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        currentElementContent = [currentElementContent stringByAppendingString:string];
}
```

You should always be setting the `currentElementContent` to `nil` at the very end of the `didEndElement` method anyway. An example for this is below:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    // Do what you want with the parser here

    // Set element content variable to nil
    currentElementContent = nil;
}
```

You may need to replace the variable: `currentElementContent` with whatever variable you have used in your parser to house the content found between the start and end tags.